# Doctrine Query Builder for entities with Join Table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

```
User ---[OneToMany]---> AcquiredSkill ---[ManyToOne]---> Skill
```

I'm having problems with creating a query using query builder in doctrine. Can someone help me convert this mysql query to a doctrine query using query builder?

```
SELECT u.*, s.*
FROM `user` u
Join `acquired_skill` ac ON ac.user_id = u.user_id
Join `skill` s ON ac.skill_id = s.skill_id
```

**Tables**

```
user
- user_id
- name
skill
- skill_id
- skill_name
acquired_skill
- as_id
- skill_id
- user_id
```

So far, this is my query but it lacks the join between the skills.

```
createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u.user_id', 'u.name')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relation seems like you have many-to-many association between user and skills you can set your entities to setup this relation like user entity will point to skill entity in a many-to-many way

**User Entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Namespace\YourBundle\Entity\Skill", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="acquired_skill",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="skill_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
private $skills;
```

**Skill Entity**

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Namespace\YourBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="skills")
 */
private $user;
```

Now in query builder you can join your user entity with skill like below

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u')
        ->innerJoin('u.skills','s')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

for further clarification see docs [`22.2.19. @ManyToMany`](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytomany)

Comment: For case `mappedBy="scheduleType"`  (camel case)  `- >join('sch.scheduleType', 'scht')`

Answer (score 0):

```
        $qb = $this->entity_manager->createQueryBuilder('u');
        $qb->select("*");
        $qb->innerJoin('Namespace\YourBundle\Entity\Aq_skill', 'ac', 'WITH', 'ac.user_id = u.user_id');
        $qb->innerJoin('Namespace\YourBundle\Entity\skill', 's', 'WITH', 'ac.skill_id = s.skill_id');

        $result = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```