# Symfony 2.8 Doctrine. Using composite primary key and ManyToMany associations

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-many, symfony-2.8

I have 2 entities - Platform and Product. In the Products table I have composite primary key by [Product ID + Platform ID]. One product can be present at many platforms so and one platform can contain many products, so the association is ManyToMany.

**The Platform entity:**

```
/**
* Platform
*
* @ORM\Table(name="Platforms")
*/
class Platform
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Platform_Id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Platform_Name", type="string", length=64)
 */
private $name;

/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="platforms", cascade={"ALL"}, indexBy="numpp")
*/
protected $products;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function addProducts($numpp)
{
    $this->products[$numpp] = new Product($numpp, $this);
}
```

**The Product entity:**

```
/**
* Product 
*
* @ORM\Table(name="Products")
*/
class Product
{
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Numpp", type="string", length=6)
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $numpp;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Platform", inversedBy="products")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Platform_Id", referencedColumnName="Platform_Id")
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $platforms;

public function __construct($numpp, Platform $platform)
{
    $this->numpp = $numpp;
    $this->platforms = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->platforms[] = $platform;
}
```

In my controller when trying to create new Product entity...

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$platform = $em->getRepository("AGAAnalyticsBundle:Platform")->find(1);
$product = new Product('05062', $platform);
$em->persist($product);
$em->flush();
```

I get an error - **Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Platform_Id', table 'dbo.Products'**

And other way using addProduct method...

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$platform = $em->getRepository("AGAAnalyticsBundle:Platform")->find(1);
$platform->addProduct('05062');
$em->flush();
```

I get an error - **The column id must be mapped to a field in class AGA\AnalyticsBundle\Entity\Platform since it is referenced by a join column of another class.**

Please help to understand where I am wrong and how I should build this relation between my entities correctly.

Comment: If there is many to many relation between platforms and production then there is no need for composite key to be present in product table, instead doctrine will a new table which will be a junction table for your platform and products

Comment: I guess this might help [Doctrine Query Builder for entities with Join Table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28470137/853360), [Doctrine Query Language, Two joins query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28616791/853360)